# upstream job should only trigger downstream job only after its sucess build using Groovy pipeline script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have two Jenkins jobs one is a groovy pipeline. other is a normal freestyle project with a plugin to trigger remote Jenkins. The groovy pipeline should only trigger another freestyle project after its successful build.

Comment: show your code, please

Comment: @StephenKing I am new to Pipeline script. I have two pipeline one is job A which was Pipeline script pipeline other was Job B With Parameterized Remote Trigger Plugin.  I am looking for a Pipeline script to Trigger other Job B only after Job A was successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`build`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/#build-build-a-job) step in your pipeline to trigger another build. If the pipeline failed before, it wouldn't reach that point.

Comment: Thanks for the reply it was Helpfull

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Please use the checkmark on the left to mark this question as solved.